# Why is there Hollywood tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Is [Hollywood tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood) alright? Shouldn't we remove it as we have more general `movie` tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't add anything to any of the questions that were using it, so I removed it from them. It should disappear in a day.

Comment: All right, who/what do I have to flag to do the same to offline Hollywood?